# How to window resize not execute on load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

i need execute commands only than window size changing i try this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    //my execute commands
});
```

It's works but this code same execute then page is opening. I don't need that i need only than window resizing. How i can avoid than page it's opening not execute this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() {});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/djwzLu6a/)

Comment: I don't know why but i tested you example on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Chrome and Mozilla but it's Doesn't work

Comment: This is why I hate jquery. You need to define a document type: <!DOCTYPE HTML>